# How to convert an array of objects to an object in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

```
product = [{id: 52, title: "cake", price: "10", category: "cakes"}]
```

I have an object with a product and it is array of object, I want to convert the above array of objects into objects like the following:

```
{id: 52, title: "cake", price: "10", category: "cakes"}
```

How could I do such a thing?

Comment: Are you asking how to access a single array element?

Comment: It's staggering how people who just learn Angular without knowing basic JS. I recommend th  OP to take some time to learn the basics on the language. Or learn about array access?

Comment: Why not loop through array and fetch individual object? Yet very basic.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to access the first element only?

Comment: Kindly specify what you exactly want get an object from single object array or having multiple objects?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)** to assign to an Object

**DEMO**

```js
product= [{id: 52, title: "cake", price: "10", category: "cakes"}]
newproduct = Object.assign({}, ...product);
    
console.log(newproduct);
```